# Getting TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list, while sending mail from Flask Mail

Tags: python, flask

Below is the code , which throws error in mail.send . The entry goes to database,but email is not getting sent. Tried a lot to resolve, but could not find type mismatch .

```
@app.route("/participate_save",methods=["POST"])
def participate_save():
    if (request.method == "POST"):
        '''Add Entry to the Database'''
        -------My CODE-------
       
        msg = Message('Hello', sender = [params['mail_user']], recipients =guardian_email)
        msg.body = "Hello Flask message sent from Flask-Mail"
        mail.send(msg)
        # mail.send_message(subject='New message from Admin of website',
        #                   sender=[params['mail_user']],
        #                   recipients=guardian_email,
        #                   body= "Thank You" ,
        #                   )

    return redirect(url_for('home'))
```

Comment: Please include the full error message.

Comment: TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list 

This is the full error message and error is thrown up in line mail.send(msg)

Comment: You should set a breakpoint and have a look at `msg` - this is not that hard. I created a short introduction to debugging a Flask introduction https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fxkco-gS4S8